# SvelteKit +server.ts & redis (Error: Socket already opened)

Tags: sockets, post, redis, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to connect to a Redis database, get and write to it and close the connection using following ts code in +server.ts (/subscribe-to-maillist):

```
// Variables and Types
import { SENDGRID_API_KEY, REDIS_CONNECTION } from '$env/static/private';
import type { RequestHandler } from './$types';

// Email
import EmailTemplate from '$main/lib/emails/SubscribedToMaillist.svelte';
import { render } from 'svelte-email';
import sendgrid from '@sendgrid/mail';

// Redis
import { createClient } from 'redis';
const client = createClient({
    url: REDIS_CONNECTION,
});

client.on("error", function (err) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ err }));
});

const emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
export const POST = (async ({ request }) => {
    const user = await request.json();
    const email = user?.email;

    console.log(email, emailRegex.test(email)); // => email, true

    if (emailRegex.test(email)) {
        await client.connect();
        const value = await client.get(email);

        console.log("value" + value, client); // not logged

        if (value === null) {
            // Write to Database
            await client.set(email, String(true));
            // Send Email
            const response = await sendEmail(email);
            const success = response[0]?.statusCode === 200 || response[0]?.statusCode === 201 || response[0]?.statusCode === 202;

            await client.disconnect();
            return new Response(JSON.stringify({ success, response: 'xxx', objres: response }));
        } else {
            await client.disconnect();
            return new Response(JSON.stringify({ success: false, response: 'xxx', objres: null }));
        }
    } else {
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({ success: false, response: 'xxx', objres: null }));
    }
}) satisfies RequestHandler;

async function sendEmail(email: string) {
    sendgrid.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);

    const emailHtml = render({
        template: EmailTemplate,
        props: {
            user: email,
        }
    });

    const options = {
        from: 'xxx <xxx.noreply@gmail.com>',
        to: email,
        subject: 'xxx',
        html: emailHtml,
    };

    return await sendgrid.send(options);
}
```

However I get following error:

```
Error: Socket already opened
    at RedisSocket.connect (xxx\node_modules\@redis\client\dist\lib\client\socket.js:48:19)
    at Commander.connect (xxx\node_modules\@redis\client\dist\lib\client\index.js:184:71)
    at POST (xxx/src/routes/subscribe-to-maillist/+server.ts:25:18)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Module.render_endpoint (xxx/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/endpoint.js:49:18)
    at async resolve (xxx/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:409:17)
    at async Module.respond (xxx/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:279:20)
    at async file:///xxx/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/dev/index.js:505:22
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't understand the error. I don't open the connection a second time, or do I? Another weird thing is, that sometimes no error appears (meaning no Response is returned to the client => no feedback) when calling the rest-endpoint and sometimes it does.

UPDATED CODE (no errors, just doesn't work, nothing is logged in the console):

+server.ts (subscribe-to-maillist):

```
// Variables and Types
import { SENDGRID_API_KEY } from '$env/static/private';
import type { RequestHandler } from './$types';

// Email
import EmailTemplate from '$main/lib/emails/SubscribedToMaillist.svelte';
import { render } from 'svelte-email';
import sendgrid from '@sendgrid/mail';

// Redis
import { redisDB } from '$server/redis';

const emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
export const POST = (async ({ request }) => {
    const user = await request.json();
    const email = user?.email;

    console.log('email', email);

    if (emailRegex.test(email)) {
        const value = await redisDB.get(email);

        console.log('value', value);

        if (value === null) {
            // Write to Database
            await redisDB.set(email, String(true));
            // Send Email
            const response = await sendEmail(email);
            const success = response[0]?.statusCode === 200 || response[0]?.statusCode === 201 || response[0]?.statusCode === 202;

            return new Response(JSON.stringify({ success, response: 'xxx', objres: response }));
        } else {
            return new Response(JSON.stringify({ success: false, response: 'xxx', objres: null }));
        }
    } else {
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({ success: false, response: 'xxx', objres: null }));
    }
}) satisfies RequestHandler;

async function sendEmail(email: string) {
    sendgrid.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);

    const emailHtml = render({
        template: EmailTemplate,
        props: {
            user: email,
        }
    });

    const options = {
        from: 'xxx - Gig-Letter <xxx.noreply@gmail.com>',
        to: email,
        subject: 'xxx!',
        html: emailHtml,
    };

    return await sendgrid.send(options);
}
```

redis.ts (only "Connected to Redis!" is logged):

```
import { REDIS_CONNECTION } from '$env/static/private';
import { createClient } from 'redis';

export const redisDB = createClient({
    url: REDIS_CONNECTION,
});

redisDB.on("connect", function () {
    console.error("Connected to Redis!");
});

redisDB.on("ready", function () {
    console.error("Redis is ready!");
});

redisDB.on("reconnecting", function () {
    console.error("Redis is reconnecting!");
});

redisDB.on("end", function () {
    console.error("Redis connection has ended!");
});

redisDB.on("error", function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});

await redisDB.connect();
```

+page.svelte (no Response is received):

```
async function mailListAction(event: Event, endpoint: string) {
    const form = event.target as HTMLFormElement;
    const data = new FormData(form);
    const email = data.get('email')?.toString();

    if (email && email.trim().length > 0) {
        const response = await fetch(`/${endpoint}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: email
            }),
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        });

        const res = await response.json();
        console.log('res', res, res.success);

        if (res.success) {
            toast.success(res.response);
        } else {
            toast.error(res?.response ?? res.message);
        }
    } else {
        toast.error('Bitte gib eine gültige E-Mail Adresse ein!');
    }
}

async function subscribeToMailList(event: Event) {
    await mailListAction(event, 'subscribe-to-maillist');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your calling `client.connect()` every time the POST function is called. You only need to call this once, right after you create your connection and set up the error handler.

However, this call is async. I'm guessing this is why you placed the call to `.connect` to the POST function. To resolve this, I usually create a separate file for my Redis connection that I name `redis.ts` and export the connection.

Usually looks like this:

```js
import { createClient } from 'redis'

export const redisClient = createClient({
    url: REDIS_CONNECTION
})

redisClient.on("error", function (err) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ err }))
})

await redisClient.connect()
```

Then I can import the `redisClient` wherever I need to talk to Redis:

```js
import { redisClient } from './redis'

redisClient.set('foo', 'bar')
```